# Using array's next() not printing the correct value

Tags: php, arrays

If I have this data, how to get current & next array value based on specific key

```
$data = array(
                array(
                    "name"=>"Joseph",
                    "location"=>"Wisconsin"
                ),
                array(
                    "name"=>"Sally",
                    "location"=>"Toronto"
                )
            );
```

This is how I am doing it, but seems to not displaying what I expect it to be. Kindly assist.

```
foreach ($data as $val)
{
    echo 'current:'.$val['name'].'<br/>';

    $nextval = next($val);
    echo 'next:'.$nextval['name'].'<br/>';
}
```

This is what is being printed out

```
current:Joseph
next:W
current:Sally
next:T
```

I expect it to be

```
current:Joseph
next:Sally
current:Sally
next:[..next value..]
```

Comment: You missunderstood what `next()` does. `next — Advance the internal array pointer of an array`

Comment: `next()` moves the array pointer from the 'name' element of `$val` to the 'location' element, and returns that value (ie 'Wisconsin' or 'Toronto'), so `$nextval` will contain (e.g.) 'Toronto'.... echoing `$nextval['name']` then is using it against a __string__ value, not an array, so it will display the first character (loose typed 'name' == 0), ie the 'T' of 'Toronto', or the 'W' of 'Wisconsin'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your foreach loop to this:

```
foreach ($data as $key=>$val)
{
    echo 'current:'.$val['name'].'<br/>';
    $nextval = $data[$key+1];
    echo 'next:'.$nextval['name'].'<br/>';
}
```

It has the behavior you asked for.

Comment: @sectus You've changed his condition block entirely while you could've just added a key to the foreach. Usually, users preffer to change their code as little as possible.

Comment: I am talking about your code. Your code has Notice error.

Comment: @sectus, it's ok. I've handled the notice, just need an idea to make the 'next()' work, the codes up there is also an example not my current code :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data) - 1; $i++) {
  $current = $data[$i];
  $next = $data[$i + 1];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use `foreach` for it because foreach do not use internal pointer of an array.

Better to use simple `for`

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
    {
    echo $array[$i]['name'] . PHP_EOL;
    if (isset($array[$i+1]['name']))
        echo $array[$i+1]['name'] . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

But. If you want to use next you could while loop.

```
while (key($array) !== null)
    {
    echo current($array)['name'];
    echo next($array)['name'];
    }
```